# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. Cursor won't return to the end of line when clicked somewhere

Tags: visual-studio

When I click somewhere in my editor view the cursor should move to the end of the nearest line of code or to the beginning of the line if it's empty. This is what I am used to at my work.
But at home I have the same VS Express 2012 for Web (everything updated), but the cursor stands blinking right at the point of the click.
I know this is not a big deal but it's a bit irritating.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have "Virtual Space" turned off.

From the Visual Studio menu Tools -> Options, Text Editor -> All Languages, and make sure "Enable Virtual Space" is unchecked.